# How to output the highest occurrence of array values when there are exactly two or more highest occurrences?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get the highest occurence in the array below using PHP, but there are 2 highest occurrences.

```
$cars = array('volvo', 'benz','honda','volvo','toyota', 'toyota');
```

I used the code below which works for a single result but when there are two highest occurrences, it outputs only one of the two.

```
$c = array_count_values($cars); 
$val = array_search(max($c), $c);
```

How can I get the highest occurrences in an array even if there are two or more similar result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can use `array_keys` with its optional 2nd argument:

```
$counts = array_count_values($cars);
$top = array_keys($counts, max($counts));
```

From the manual:

> If the optional search_value [2nd argument] is specified, then only the keys for that value are returned. Otherwise, all the keys from the array are returned.

For the input given in the OP, the result is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "volvo"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "toyota"
}
```

[See it live on 3v4l.org.](https://3v4l.org/kY6HJ)